# Get the sum of a count column in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, count, sum

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
    dtc.coupon_type_company_name,  
    COUNT(*) * dtc.coupon_type_company_coupon_amount AS 'Total_Coupon_To_Be_Used',
    dtc.coupon_type_company_coupon_months_combinable
FROM 
    [dbo].[coupon_type_Company_User] dtcu
JOIN 
    coupon_type_Company dtc ON dtcu.coupon_type_Company_ID = dtc.id
JOIN 
    person p ON dtcu.userID = p.userID
WHERE 
    coupon_type_company_coupon_is_combinable = 1 
    OR coupon_type_company_has_coupon = 1 
    AND dtc.companyID = 1081
    AND p.is_active = 1
GROUP BY
    dtc.coupon_type_company_name,dtc.coupon_type_company_coupon_amount,
    dtc.coupon_type_company_coupon_months_combinable
```

This returns the following:

[image]

What I want to have however is just one column and one row that should take the SUM of my middle column (`count(*)*dtc.coupon_type_company_coupon_amount`).

How could I achieve this and prevent doing this in my code backend (C#)

Comment: Wrap it in another `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap your query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Total_Coupon_To_Be_Used) AS the_sum
FROM (
   your query
) s
```

Comment: This works perfectly! What I was wondering however is why we need to add the last character after closing the brackets. Could you explain why this '`s`' is needed?

Comment: I don't think your code will run if you remove it.  In SQL Server, you must alias subqueries in `FROM` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: The syntax for a [`from` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) allows an _alias_ on a _derived table_. What it fails to make clear is that an alias may be required, as in this case. Since it exists here only to satisfy the syntax requirement you can use an alias like `as Placeholder`, `Appendix`, `Froderick`, ... .

Answer (score 2):

Use a "Table Expression", as in:

```
select sum(Total_Coupon_To_Be_Used) from (
  SELECT dtc.coupon_type_company_name,  
    count(*) * dtc.coupon_type_company_coupon_amount as 'Total_Coupon_To_Be_Used',
    dtc.coupon_type_company_coupon_months_combinable
  FROM [dbo].[coupon_type_Company_User] dtcu
  JOIN coupon_type_Company dtc ON dtcu.coupon_type_Company_ID = dtc.id
  JOIN person p ON dtcu.userID = p.userID
  WHERE coupon_type_company_coupon_is_combinable = 1 
     or coupon_type_company_has_coupon = 1 
    and dtc.companyID = 1081
    AND p.is_active = 1
  GROUP BY
    dtc.coupon_type_company_name,dtc.coupon_type_company_coupon_amount,
    dtc.coupon_type_company_coupon_months_combinable
  ) x
```